# custom htaccess ErrorDocument page CSS loads weird in Chrome

Tags: css, .htaccess, google-chrome

I have a custom ErrorDocument setup for my website with custom CSS. The path for the CSS is absolute, so it can find the file. For some reason though in Chrome the page looks like with no CSS at all and when I checked the loaded resources it did find the CSS file but the content just shows some random chinese symbols instead of the CSS. On the "normal" pages the CSS displays just as expected, it is just on the ErrorDocument pages it is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself. I guess the two CSS files weren't UTF-8 encoded and for some reason Chrome didn't detected that for some reason and still tried to load them as if they were UTF-8. So converting them to UTF-8 solved the problem.
Also setting the charset will solve the issue:

```
<style src="..." charset="UTF-8">
```